# IONIC 2 - Reload de paginas do app

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic2

Estou desenvolvendo um app onde ele é quase todo montado a partir de dados de uma API em um servidor externo, buscando informações em um Oracle de um cliente.

Após feito o login, tenho na HomePage a função `ngInit` que faz a busca dos dados nessa API externa. 
Quando eu navego em outras páginas do app e volto para a HomePage, tenho que ficar buscando os dados novamente, porque ao que parece, ao sair da HomePage os dados carregados nas variáveis anteriormente estão vazios.

Tem uma maneira mais inteligente de se fazer isso, ou seja, não ficar chamando toda vez a API quando entrar na HomePage?

Comment: você está utilizando providers para consumir os dados da API?

Comment: não estou Felipe....estou usando assim:

Answer (score 0):

```
getMetaLoja() {
this.idempresa = this.navParams.get('empresa'); 

var link = 'http://xxxxxxx.com/xxx/xxx/xxxxx.php';
var data = JSON.stringify({idEmpresa: this.idempresa});

this.http.post(link, data).subscribe(data => {
  this.data.response = data._body;
  this.metaloja = JSON.parse(<string>this.data.response);
  if(this.metaloja === "" || this.metaloja === null || this.metaloja.length === 0)
  {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'A meta da sua loja não foi encontrada',
    message: 'Por favor, verifique sua conexão de internet ou entre em contato com a administração do App para mais informações',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        handler: () => {
        this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      }
    }
    ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }       
  }, error => {
    console.log("Oooops!");
  });
}
```

Comment: Junior pesquise por Providers utilize o comando Ionic generate provider loja;

Comment: Vou pesquisar Felipe, pode deixar. Obrigado!